# Using Selenium with Python to click on a href button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium and python to automate web tasks. I have tried using multiple different functions to try to click on the button I need:

```
<a href="/crm/tab/Reports">Reports</a>

.find_element_by_link_text("Reports").click()
.find_element_by_id
.find_element_by_name
.find_element_by_class_name
.find_element_by_css_selector
```

Can't seem to make this work, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using "find_elements_by_xpath". Right click and copy the XPATH from the browser.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've tried copying the xpath and it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Try wait.until or sleep, before click.

Answer (score 0):

Using explicit waits could potentially solve the problem. For explicit waits, you can either use the ID or XPATH. I prefer using XPATH. For getting the XPATH, right click on the element, click *Inspect*, right click on `<a href="/crm/tab/Reports">Reports</a>` and choose *Copy*, and then *Copy XPATH*. Now that we have the XPATH, do the following:

```
button_xpath = "the xpath of your element"
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, button_xpath))).click()
```

The above code will wait up to 10 seconds until the button element is found. If the element is not found, a TimeoutException will be given.

The following imports are necessary:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```